# onCreate always called if navigating back with intent

Tags: android, back-stack, activity-stack

I have an activity called HomeActivity that has a SurfaceView and shows a camera preview picture. This activity is quiet heavy and feels slow if you are starting/restarting it.

So I made some investigations and found out, that somehow always the onCreate method is being called. In my opinion this should not happen if the Activity has already been started?

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) says : 
Called when the activity is first created. This is where you should do all of your normal static set up: create views, bind data to lists, etc. This method also provides you with a Bundle containing the activity's previously frozen state, if there was one.
Always followed by onStart().

Here is the method, that handles going back:

```
protected void gotoHome() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(SomeOtherActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Edit:

Here is how I am leaving HomeActivity ... nothing special:

```
final Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SomeOtherActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Make sure you don't finish() HomeActivity when starting another Activity from it.

Comment: onCreat() calls when your are going back with method `gotoHome()`?

Comment: @Egor I am not calling finish()

Comment: Did you check if the onDestroy method from HomeActivity is being called?

Comment: @JonathanNaguin Yes, it being destroyed after the other activity has started, this is the problem, but how do I avoid this? Is it actual possible?

Comment: Wait, every time you launch SomeOtherActivity it is immediately destroying HomeActivity? Is this on a device or the emulator?

Comment: @matt5784 Yes, this is what is happening. I am working on two devices, but I will try it in the emulator too!

Comment: Try it in the emulator and see if the behavior is the same.

Comment: @matt5784 I tried it in the emulator. I looks as if the HomeActivity gets destoryed and is new created once the gotoHome() funktion is called.

Comment: @Mark are you releasing the camera when you leave the HomeActivity?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, when you want to return to the HomeActivity, you need to use these flags:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Here's the relevant section from the documentation on Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP:

> The currently running instance of activity B in the above example will
>   either receive the new intent you are starting here in its
>   onNewIntent() method, or be itself finished and restarted with the new
>   intent. If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the
>   default) and you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same
>   intent, then it will be finished and re-created; for all other launch
>   modes or if FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be
>   delivered to the current instance's onNewIntent().

Comment: Thank you very much! Facepalm... could self have this idea!

Comment: Sometimes it amazes me how quickly you can get a useful answer around here ;-) Glad to be of help.

Comment: Hi David ,My activitiy's oncreate gets called everytime I return from its child activity,Can u pls help me out?

Comment: @NancyY please open a new question and describe your problem, post relevant code, etc. Adding a comment to this answer isn't the right way to get attention.