# Modification of the back stack in Android

Tags: android, back-stack

I would like to modify the back stack in my Android application as such:

Right now, here is the flow:

A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F

I want to be able to modify the back stack, so that when the user goes to activity F, D and E are erased from the stack. so the flow is F -> C if the user hits the back.

Also, from F, the user is able to go to activity B, this should erase C, D, E, and F as well.

I've seen some information on being able to clear the stack, or remove the top item, but I want to remove a number of items from the stack, when an activity is triggered.

Any help is appreciated, thanks very much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can build an intent with the flag `intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` from F to C. Then you will have to call startActivity() with the intent and trigger this to occur onBackPressed or something similar.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, C.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(i)
```

See this answer, which also deals with ensuring that C won't be restarted when you navigate back to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11347608/1003511

What `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` will do is go go back to the most recent instance of activity C on the stack and then clear everything which is above it. However, this can cause the activity to be re-created. If you want to ensure it will be the same instance of the activity, use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` as well. From the documentation:

> The currently running instance of activity B in the above example will
>   either receive the new intent you are starting here in its
>   onNewIntent() method, or be itself finished and restarted with the new
>   intent. If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the
>   default) and you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same
>   intent, then it will be finished and re-created; for all other launch
>   modes or if FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be
>   delivered to the current instance's onNewIntent().

Edit: Here is a code sample similar to what you want to do:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Intent a = new Intent(this, C.class);
        a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(a);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

code sample source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9398171/1003511

Answer (score 2):

What you need is  `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` which must be added in Activity tag in manifest file. It stops all the activities to go onto stack  who has this tag into Activity tag in manifest.

Example code

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.xx.xx.ActivityName"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"


        </activity>
```

and make sure that you call `finish()`(after starting another activity) method in those activity you don't want to be on activity stack.

Comment: Hello, this would make the activity completely disappear from the history which isn't what I want. I want the activity to disappear only after a certain other activity has been fired. Thanks for the help though!