# Android: navigating up to the parent activity recreates the parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have a SearchAcvitity which has a child PersonActivity. Each are FragmentActivity's. Here's my manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".SearchActivity" android:label="@string/search_title">
</activity>


<activity android:name=".PersonActivity" android:label="@string/person_title"
            android:parentActivityName=".SearchActivity" >
            <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".SearchActivity" />
</activity>
```

From SearchFragment, I start PersonActivity like so:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PersonActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

This alone adds the left-facing caret alongside the app icon in PersonFragment. When I press this icon, it recreates SearchAcvitiy (and fragment), so its previous state is lost.

When I instead press the back button from PersonFragment, it goes back to SearchActivity's SearchFragment via onResume(...) and its state is intact. How can I make this happen with the up action?

Please note that I don't make this call in PersonFragment:

getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Answer (score 15):

UP navigation launches the parent Activity with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. The standard behaviour of this flag is to finish all Activities that are on top of the parent Activity in the task stack **including the parent Activity itself** and then launch a new instance of the parent Activity**. If you want to resume the existing instance of the parent Activity, then you can set the following in the manifest for the parent Activity:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

When CLEAR_TOP and SINGLE_TOP are used together, this will resume an existing instance of the parent Activity. In this case, `onCreate()` will not be called on the resumed parent Activity, but instead `onNewIntent()` will be called instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think someone may have asked the question before: [onCreate being called on Activity A in up navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216410/oncreate-being-called-on-activity-a-in-up-navigation)

Basically it is expected behavior. You need to save state into the bundle, which you can restore in onCreate.