# Avoid Fetching Data from JSON again and again

Tags: java, android, json, android-activity, lifecycle

I am parsing JSON data from server in MainActivity but whenever I switch to another Activity and then again calling MainActivity... here comes the problem, it again hitting the JSON url, again fetching the data from JSON.

WHY? Whereas I already downloaded data from JSON

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;

    ActorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");

        ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), actorsList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
            }
        });
    }


    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Actors actor = new Actors();

                        actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
                        actor.setDescription(object.getString("description"));
                        actor.setDob(object.getString("dob"));
                        actor.setCountry(object.getString("country"));
                        actor.setHeight(object.getString("height"));
                        actor.setSpouse(object.getString("spouse"));
                        actor.setChildren(object.getString("children"));
                        actor.setImage(object.getString("image"));

                        actorsList.add(actor);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                //------------------>>

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if(result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You can put flag to solve this

Comment: Are you finishing MainActivity when your firing intent for another activity

Comment: You can put a flag in the SharedPreference for that and check that flag.

Comment: Both the ways - I am calling MainActivity from SecondActivity using onBackPressed() and also calling MainActivity from ThirdActivity using Intent... so what are the best ways of doing this ?

Comment: use shared pref or make flag

Comment: U can use flag or declare boolean and make condition for new JSONAsyncTask().

Comment: Use SharedPreference and Flag for your activity.

Comment: small doubt about set flag value,if server updated then what happen.. not get updated data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a static variable

```
 static boolean flag=false;
 static ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;
```

Then before calling the AsyncTask check if flag is true or false

```
if(!flag){
 actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>(); //use this inside if statement
 new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");
flag=true;
}
```

so only if the flag is false the async task is executed...
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes now its not hitting JSON api again, but even not showing existing data into ListView... what could be the reasons ?

Comment: @Oreo Its Not hitting the api then How could you get the Data in your List view because you arraylist is populaing you asynch task  .. You should use singleton Approach to save the data you got by calling your api for the  firstime.

Comment: is there an exception being called?

Comment: @Ben no but not getting existing data into ListView (data i got when I hit the json very first time)

Comment: try making the actorList as static

Comment: here is the tutorial which I am following and Oreo too: http://www.wingnity.com/blog/android-json-parsing-and-image-loading-tutorial/  I just added a second activity and then coming back from that activity to MainActivity. Let's try at your end.. I am also trying to resolve this issue...

Comment: Thank you so much Sophie.. for your work, I hope @Ben will also try at his end...

Comment: device's back button "finish()"

Comment: :) but I am trying with Intent, as you wrote you need solution for the both the cases

Comment: @Ben did you find any solution ?

Comment: Every time actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>(); is called the arrayList becomes null...so i used it inside the if statement..

Comment: getting : NPE, listview.setAdapter(adapter); please check sample at your end... http://pastebin.com/BvBSFXfK

Comment: use static  ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;

Comment: @Ben still facing same issue when I am coming back from Activity C to Activity A...

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment "`I am calling MainActivity from SecondActivity using onBackPressed() and also calling MainActivity from ThirdActivity using Intent.`"

At SecondActivity onBackPressed() : simply calling `finish()` will not reload the MainActivity, hence it will not reload and call web service again.

Another option is to have a flag, saved in `shared preferences`.

Steps:

1. Save a flag `didCallService = true` to shared preferences when the service is called first time. Save the `json` response also in the s`hared preference` as a string.
2. When you reach `onCreate()` on `MainActivity` from other 2 activities check if `didCallService` from user defaults is true. If so do not call the service again.

Answer (score 0):

Take one `boolean` variable and initialize it to true and also save it's state to `sharedpreference`. Now when `MainActivity` starts, check if this `boolean` is true or not using `sharedpreference`. If it is true, fetch `JSON` and turn `boolean` to false and also save state of `boolean` to `sharedpreference`. Now after this whenever `MainActivity` is called, because boolean is false, `JSON` will not be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "savedInstanceState" varibale for this purpose please check below code

```
if(savedInstanceState==null)
{
     new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");
}
```

first time when you start activity its savedInstanceState is null next time t has value so add above condition in your code.

Comment: is it helpful to you reply in comment?

Comment: Tried this : http://pastebin.com/fCLZDXK4 and please let me know what I am missing ?

Comment: YES getting NPE - listview.setAdapter(adapter); I am getting NPE when coming from SecondActivity to MainActivity

Comment: please debug it I think many time json calling issue is solved for null pointer I think apater object has null value debug and check value for adapter and also check many time json calling issue solved or not

Answer (score 0):

Use [singleTask](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file add this property to `MainActivity`,

```
<activity ..
      android:launchMode= "singleTask" />
```

This will reload the instance of MainActivity and `onCreate()` won't be called, instead new intent will be available to use in `onNewIntent()` method.

Comment: tried still hitting JSON api, when i am coming from SecondActivity to MainActivity

Comment: I don't believe this, you have code to fetch in only onCreate() and still fetching with singleTask, MAGICAL.!

Comment: actually what's happening, for the first showing progressdialog > fetching data > populating listview then I moved to second activity, now I tapped on back (what i saw) again showing progress dialog > fetching data > populating listview

Comment: I am not using finish anywhere in MainActivity, calling SecondActivity like this: listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
     long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), actorsList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
   }
  });

Comment: use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19216471/903469) , put your code to execute task in null condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108484/discussion-between-oreo-and-mkjparekh).