# Override onSavedInstanceState: savedInstanceState object is always null

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities (A and B). Activity A calls activity B. Activity B has Back (Up) button like this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Now when this UP button is pressed, onCreate of activity A is again called. In the activity A, there is a `classId` variable (which I got from an `Intent`) which I want to retain. For this I have following code in my `onCreate` of activity A:

```
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            classId = intent.getIntExtra("CLASS_ID", 0);
        }
        else
        {
            classId = savedInstanceState.getInt("CLASS_ID");
        }
```

I have also overriden the `onSavedInstanceState` method:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    savedInstanceState.putInt("CLASS_ID", classId);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

I am following this SO answer:
[onCreate being called on Activity A in up navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216410/oncreate-being-called-on-activity-a-in-up-navigation)

The problem I am facing is that when I come again to activity A by passing back button in activity B, onCreate gets called and I found savedInstanceState to be NULL.

**Edit:**

Is there any other way to save my `classId` variable so that when I return again to activity A, I can use that?

**Edit 2**

If I set launch mode of my activity A to `SingleTop` in the manifest file, my issue gets resolved. Is it the right approach?

Comment: would be less complex if you use singleTon

Comment: @GIBINTHOMAS - Can you please explain in detail.

Answer (score 1):

You should not suppose that `onSaveInstanceState` called each time you go to next activity.See the docs

**This method is called before an activity may be killed so that when it comes back some time in the future it can restore its state. For example, if activity B is launched in front of activity A, and at some point activity A is killed to reclaim resources, activity A will have a chance to save the current state of its user interface via this method so that when the user returns to activity A, the state of the user interface can be restored via onCreate(Bundle) or onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle).**

You may further consult with official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

Comment: I have put a debug point in the onSavedInstanceState method and it is getting called when I am switching to activity B. But now when I am returning to activity A, the savedInstanceState bundle object is NULL.

Comment: i am not sure but then perhaps you should call super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState); first

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class SingletonHolder {

    //your id here as what data type you want


    private  static SingletonHolder instance;

    public static SingletonHolder getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SingletonHolder();
        }
        return instance;
    }

   //set getter setter here
}
```

If not successfull feel free to comment

Comment: Is this the standard way of saving variables while switching between the activities OR just a work around?

Comment: Its a logic which we use actually , Its a concept its purely native and its java

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `launchMode` of the activity A to `singleTop` in the `mainfest` file like this:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

I followed this question on SO: [Setting launchMode="singleTask" vs setting activity launchMode="singleTop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773928/setting-launchmode-singletask-vs-setting-activity-launchmode-singletop)

By using this approach, activity A is not destroyed and when I just finish the activity B or click UP navigation in activity B, the existing instance of activity A is launched again.